# When to use classifier

Tags: measure-word

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
我吃个苹果。
Or it should be either,
我吃苹果
Or,
我吃一个苹果

Is it correct to use classifiers without any number and demonstratives?

Answer (score 1):

- Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Yes, it is correct. The number "one" can sometimes be omitted before the classifier.

我吃苹果

I eat apples (generally, no specific number or apples implied).

我吃一个苹果

I eat one apple (not two,  not half. Number is important here.).

我吃這个苹果

I eat this apple (with the demonstrative, a specific apple).

我吃个苹果

I eat an apple (no specific apple implied, no emphasis on number).

Answer (score -1):

You shall add "了" after "吃" to indicate the action has been completed. Then all sentences make sense as shown below (with or without the classifier):

我吃"了"个苹果

我吃"了"苹果

我吃"了"一个苹果

However, the sentences you have cited are acceptable in the casual conversations below:

Q: 你(想)吃什麼? A: 我(想)吃苹果, or 我(想)吃個苹果, or 我(想)吃ㄧ個苹果. All are fine.

Q: 你(要)吃"幾個"(苹果)? A: 我(要)吃"ㄧ個"苹果.

The examples show that a classifier must accompany the noun if the questioner expects a quantity indicated in the response.